# Why are hearts of t-structures of triangulated categories abelian?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories, triangulated-categories

Is there any reason why this is true? I haven't found any proof yet.

I know what triangulated categories and t-structures are, however I'm not convinced that hearts of t-structures are abelian categories.

Comment: In some way, this is a weird question : $t$-structure were defined originally to find abelian subcategories of triangulated categories. So hearts of $t$-structures are abelian by purpose.

Answer (score 7):

I understand your question as being a reference request.

This is a theorem first proved in Beilinson, Bernstein and Deligne's paper *Faisceaux pervers*, published in Astérisque.  The result in question is Théorème 1.3.6.

A proof in English appears in Kashiwara and Schapira's book *Sheaves on manifolds*, published by Springer.  The result is Proposition 10.1.11.

Comment: https://amathew.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/trying-to-understand-bbd/ is a good reference.